# What is the PyTorch equivalent to torch's module.backward()?

Tags: pytorch, torch

Torch has a [module.backward](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/module.md#gradinput-backwardinput-gradoutput) function that takes an input and gradient output. Is there an equivalent call in PyTorch that I can use instead of calling `.backward()` on some output variable?

Comment: Are you looking for this?

    def new_backward(module, input):
        module(input).backward()

Comment: Not too familiar with torch, but I would guess it's [this one](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.backward)?

Comment: If you call `backward()`, you can access gradient of each parameter first by calling `network.parameters` and than using `param.grad` on each to obtain it's gradient value. I don't think there is an equivalent, but you could probably work out your case that way.